# Merge Array if same main value

Tags: php, arrays

```
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 33
                    [food_category_id] => 51
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 33
                    [food_category_id] => 12
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 34
                    [food_category_id] => 62
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 35
                    [food_category_id] => 2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 35
                    [food_category_id] => 80
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 35
                    [food_category_id] => 99
                )
```

here is the query that generated the array

```
$query = $this->writedb->query("SELECT * FROM `food_to_category` WHERE food_id IN ( " . $implode_data . " )");
```

Above is the output , but how do combine the array into 1 array if food_id is the same ? now showing is all independant array , wanted to combine if food_id are the same

Comment: Do a group by in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in easy way using GROUP BY statement, but you also have to use GROUP CONCAT to mantain all the category ids

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
"SELECT food_id, GROUP_CONCAT(food_category_id) FROM `food_to_category` WHERE food_id IN ( " . $implode_data . " ) GROUP BY food_id"
```

I will produce similar result

```
[3] => Array
 (
      [food_id] => 35
      [food_category_id] => "2,80,99"
 )
```

if you want to have category ids as an array you can explode it by comma